# Python merge lists

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to get the sum of numbers from a [website](http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_213060.html). I do this:

```
lst = list()
url = raw_input('Enter - ')
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
tags = soup('span')
for tag in tags:
    lst.append(map(int,tag.contents))
print lst
```

But if I am not mistaken, I now have a sublist for every number. Thus, `sum(lst)` doesn't work. How can I either merge the sublists or put the numbers in a single list to start with? Thanks!

Comment: So what do you get when you print `lst`?

Comment: Have you tried [`list.extend()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types)?

Comment: Yes lst, sorry for the confusion. Or more exactly, sum(lst)

Comment: And for sum(lst) I got: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the following:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_213060.html'
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
tags = soup('span')
lst = [int(tag.text) for tag in tags]
print(sum(lst))
```

**Output**

```
2838
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great! Could you tell me why the `[0]` is needed?

Comment: On second thoughts, it is actually better to use `tag.text` instead of `tag.contents[0]`. See updated answer above.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the [built-in `sum()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum):

```
comments = soup('span', class_="comments")
sum_coments = sum(int(comment.get_text(strip=True)) for comment in comments)
print(sum_coments)  # prints 2838
```

Note that [`.get_text()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) is used here which returns a "text" of an element as opposed to [`.contents`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children) which is a list of texts of element's children.

Note that I've also improved the locator and also check `span`s to have `comments` class.